# Another term for divine beings that predates the Gods

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a small mythology in which I have two separate types of divine entities combine to give birth to the first gods.  I strongly suspect one of these divine entities will be named Titans.  However, I need a separate and distinct term for the second type of divine being, ideally pulling from mythologies of the past.

Ideally the term would be associated more with creativity and/or the ability to generate something new, as that's the defining trait of the 'mother' of the gods.  A term for a divine being associated with mothering would also work, though theoretically I'd rather emphasis creativity then specific mothering.  Still, I'd settle for any good term for a divine being that predates, and in some ways is greater then, the gods.

Comment: Diiiiiiid you try a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/divine)?

Comment: In Greek mythology, the *Titans* preceded (and warred with) the *Gods*. Though for your application, with a focus on aloof yet creative power, you might like *demiurge*.

Comment: similarly to @DanBron's suggestion, howsabout a neoligism - "Theoturge" - a creator or producer of Gods.

Comment: This seems more up [mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/)'s alley.

Comment: Gods'  Mom and Dad   .    In this case, it's turtles all the way **up**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general term for such beings is *gods*.

There are a few religious views that use *gods* (or a term generally translated as such) for a specific group within a set of beings also called *gods* (or a term generally translated as such), including as you reference using *gods* specifically of the Olympians who came after the Titans, though both groups could also be reasonably called *gods*. There are also views which combine a polytheistic *gods* with a monotheistic *god* in the same mythos, as per Neoplatonism and the polytheistic forms of Gnosticism. In such views the original creator is called the *demiurge* though there's no linguistic reason why one couldn't have two or more *demiurges*.

> Ideally the term would be associated more with creativity and/or the ability to generate something new

*Demiurge* means "creator" or "producer", from an earlier more specific sense that meant "craftsperson" or "artisan".